# What does “Nate Silver’s deal with ESPN is about more than Disney vs. the New York Times” mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

Time magazine (July 22) reported the move of Nate Silver, baseball-stats analyst who turned election data-cruncher, and predicted the last two presidential elections more accurately than politicians and pundits from New York Times to ESPN under the headline, “There is a 99.45% chance that Nate Silver is changing journalism.”

http://entertainment.time.com/2013/07/22/there-is-a-99-45-chance-that-nate-silver-is-changing-journalism/#ixzz2ZoAXD0ZQ

In the subhead line, the Time says:

> “His deal with ESPN is about **more than Disney vs. the New York Times.**
>   If Silver-style analysis spreads, everyone can win.” What does “His
>   deal with ESPN is about more than Disney vs. the New York Times?”

What is the legitimate link between Disney and the New York Times? Is this a well-turned expression?

Comment: I do not think that "Disney vs the New York Times" is a common expression.  According to wikipedia, Disney owns ESPN, so I think that is merely the author referring to the 'parent company' of the two organizations.  Further in the article, he mentions that Silverman's deal was "with Disney".

Comment: @Gus Yep. No need to rely on Wikipedia. ;) http://thewaltdisneycompany.com/disney-companies/media-networks

Comment: To the person who casted down-vote:
I would like to know why you gave the down-vote. Please tell me concrete reasons for why in the comment box below. This can be a common knowledge to 100 % of native English speakers, but not to many non-native speakers who are allowed to be a part of EL&U users.

Comment: The expression in bold simply implies: "[There's more than meets the eye](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/There+is+more+to+than+meets+the+eye)"

Comment: Yoichi, I agree with you that not native speakers should be admitted as a part of EL&U, even because some of them, as it seems to me, are able to speak better than natives, but, for what is worth, I do see no downvotes cast to this question, as your [reputation](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/3119/yoichi-oishi?tab=reputation) page shows.

Comment: Carlro_R. Thanks for your encouragement for entitlement of non native speakers in EL&U community. As for down-vote I requested for the voter’s clarification for reason, I saw it within 5 to 10 minutes after posting this question. The down-vote has gone away in 15 minutes and was replaced with an up-vote. Down-vote(s)-no-later-than-posting question frequently had happened some time ago, for which I posted a complain in meta EL&U section once. The practice has ceased recently, but I observed the resurgence of it again this morning. Perhaps I’d better to deal with this subject in Meta section.

Comment: @Yoichi Oishi if I were you, I'd leave well alone. I have been advocating that downvotes should be explained in comments to no avail. I still get anonymous downvotes today. Be philosophical about it, your questions enjoy an immense popularity that 97% of users can only dream about!

Comment: Mari-Lou A. Though I think down-voters who can't give clear reasons for their doing so in comment are coward persons, your advice is telling. I'll try to be philosophical as you suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As detailed by [Politico](http://www.politico.com/blogs/media/2013/07/how-espn-and-abc-landed-nate-silver-168888.html), ESPN and ABC News, both of which are owned by Disney, lured Nate Silver away from the New York Times as the NYT's licensing agreement for Silver's political progostication blog, [FiveThirtyEight](http://fivethirtyeight.blogs.nytimes.com/), was due to expire.

As the rest of the Time Magazine article goes on to elaborate, Nate Silver's move means much more than his leaving one employer (the New York Times) for another (Disney, ESPN's parent company), or taking FiveThirtyEight.com from the New York Times to ESPN.

The next-to-last bullet point in the article probably best summarizes the writer's point:

> The distinctive thing about Silver’s deal with Disney, and maybe what
>   intrigued him most, is its scope: his new venture will try to apply
>   his kind of analysis to fields from entertainment to science to
>   technology.